# navigation drawer not closing when clicking links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile-website

So I'm making a website and I made a mobile drawer for my nav links, it opens fine when I click on the button with 3 lines in it and to close it I did a backdrop, but now when I click a link to go to the next page the nav drawer doesn't close,  to close it I have to tap on the backdrop screen and I want the drawer to close when I click on a page link.

`app.js`

```
  state = {
    sideDrawerOpen: false
  };

  drawerToggleClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen };
    });
  };

  backdropClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ sideDrawerOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    let backdrop

    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler} />
    }
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
            <Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} />
            <SideDrawer show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen} />
            {backdrop}
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/Contact' component={Contact} />
            <Route exact path='/Events' component={Events} />
            <Route exact path='/About' component={About} />
            <Route exact path='/Gallery' component={Gallery} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

`drawer.js`

```
         <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/About">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/Events">Events</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/Gallery">Gallery</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/Contact">Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<Router>` is rendered inside the component in `app.js`, so changing a page will not trigger an unmount or reset your state. You can, however, detect a page change in `componentDidUpdate`, and use that to manually close your drawer:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { location } = this.props;
  if (location !== prevProps.location && this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
    this.setState({ sideDrawerOpen: false });
  }
}
```

Additional reading: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history/history-is-mutable